# Testing for significant differences between interaction terms in a multiple regression

Tags: multiple-regression, interaction

Can someone explain what it means to test for significant differences between interaction terms in a multiple regression? I understand testing to see if each interaction term is significant, but I don’t know how you test for differences between interaction terms. The situation is experiment with three conditions, a continuous measured variable (let’s say religiosity), and dependent variable (let’s say risk ratings). Here is the description of the analysis: “We conducted a multiple regression analysis, entering dummy-coded variables representing experimental condition, religiosity (continuous), and the interaction of each dummy-coded variable with religiosity as predictors of risk ratings. The analysis yielded a significant difference between the Condition 1 × religiosity and both the Condition 2 × religiosity, β = x.xx, p < .01, and the Condition 2 × religiosity interactions, β = −0.21, p < .01.” Thanks in advance!